# Include Dynamic Custom Xamarin Xaml View Control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

Hello I have a repeating carousel I've copied for each deparment that I want to consolidate and make into a custom xaml view control. Here is the original carousel view I have copied several times in my page. I want to figure out how to clean this up with something externally from the page.

```
<StackLayout Padding="10">

<Label Text="Human Resources" FontSize="Large"
        TextColor="#000000"></Label>
            
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding HumanResourcesCollection}"
                PeekAreaInsets="75"
                IndicatorView="Indicator"
                HeightRequest="275">

    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="10"></LinearItemsLayout>

    </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

    <CarouselView.EmptyView>

        <StackLayout>

            <Label Text="No results for this department"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>

            <Label Text="Contact your manager for more information"
                    FontSize="Medium"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>

        </StackLayout>

    </CarouselView.EmptyView>

    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>

            <StackLayout Padding="10">

                <helper:LayoutGradient StartColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"
                                        EndColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"
                                        OptionCorner="True"
                                        RadiusCorner="25"
                                        DirectionColor="False">

                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnDepartmentSelected></TapGestureRecognizer>

                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                    <Frame.Content>

                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Opacity=".35" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End">

                                <Image.Source>

                                    <FontImageSource Size="148" Glyph="{Binding Comments}"
                                                        FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontIcons}"
                                                        Color="Blue"></FontImageSource>
                                </Image.Source>

                            </Image>

                            <StackLayout
                                            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        ></Label>

                                <Label Text="{Binding Version}" FontSize="Small"></Label>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>

                                            
                                                
                    </Frame.Content>

                </helper:LayoutGradient>
                                    
                <Label Padding="0, 10, 0, 10" Text="{Binding Description}"
                        TextColor="#808080"
                        FontSize="Medium"></Label>

            </StackLayout>

        </DataTemplate>

    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

</CarouselView>

<IndicatorView x:Name="Indicator" IndicatorColor="LightBlue"
                SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"></IndicatorView>
```

How Can I dynamically add the title and collection? I've gotten the carousel view to show but cannot get it to show when involving data and properties.

```
xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Program.Controls"

<control:CarouselControl Department="Human Resources" Collection="{Binding HumanResourcesCollection}"></control:CarouselControl>

<control:CarouselControl Department="Administration" Collection="{Binding AdministrationCollection}"></control:CarouselControl>

<control:CarouselControl Department="Operations" Collection="{Binding OperationsCollection}"></control:CarouselControl>
```

Am I in the right thinking or way off base? Been messing around with properties in a ViewModel but don't know enough to get it working. Thanks all.

```
public string Department {get; set;}

public ObservableCollectoin<DeparmentModel> Collection {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you had used Custom ContentView , you need use [bindable property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) to binding value between the elements in **ContentView** and **Parent ContentPage**

#### in CarouselControl.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
//...
x:Name="view" // set the name of CarouselControl
>
```

```
<StackLayout Padding="10">

<Label Text="Human Resources" FontSize="Large"
        TextColor="#000000"></Label>
            
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference view}, Path=Collection}"
                PeekAreaInsets="75"
                IndicatorView="Indicator"
                HeightRequest="275">

    <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="10"></LinearItemsLayout>

    </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

    <CarouselView.EmptyView>

        <StackLayout>

            <Label Text="No results for this department"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>

            <Label Text="Contact your manager for more information"
                    FontSize="Medium"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>

        </StackLayout>

    </CarouselView.EmptyView>

<CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>

            <StackLayout Padding="10">

                <helper:LayoutGradient StartColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"
                                        EndColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"
                                        OptionCorner="True"
                                        RadiusCorner="25"
                                        DirectionColor="False">

                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnDepartmentSelected></TapGestureRecognizer>

                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                    <Frame.Content>

                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Opacity=".35" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="End">

                                <Image.Source>

                                    <FontImageSource Size="148" Glyph="{Binding Comments}"
                                                        FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontIcons}"
                                                        Color="Blue"></FontImageSource>
                                </Image.Source>

                            </Image>

                            <StackLayout
                                            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        ></Label>

                                <Label Text="{Binding Version}" FontSize="Small"></Label>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>

                                            
                                                
                    </Frame.Content>

                </helper:LayoutGradient>
                                    
                <Label Padding="0, 10, 0, 10" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference view}, Path=Description}"
                        TextColor="#808080"
                        FontSize="Medium"></Label>

            </StackLayout>

        </DataTemplate>

    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

</CarouselView>

<IndicatorView x:Name="Indicator" IndicatorColor="LightBlue"
                SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"></IndicatorView>
```

#### in CarouselControl.xaml.cs

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CollectionProperty =
              BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Collection), typeof(ObservableCollection<YourModel>), typeof(CarouselControl));

        public ObservableCollection<YourModel> Collection
        {
            get => (ObservableCollection<YourModel>)GetValue(CollectionProperty );
            set => SetValue(CollectionProperty , value);
        }
```

Note : YourModel here is the mdoel that contains the properties of the CarouselView , like

```
public class YourModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }

        //...other proerty in CarouselView
    }
```

#### in ContentPage

```
<control:CarouselControl Department="Human Resources" Collection="{Binding HumanResourcesCollection}"></control:CarouselControl>
```

You just need to binding the source of Collection, the property **Title**
had been set when you init the **HumanResourcesCollection** so you don't need to binding it again .

Here is some similar case that you can have a refer

[How to bind a CommandParameter in a ContentView to an element in the parent ContentPage in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116686/how-to-bind-a-commandparameter-in-a-contentview-to-an-element-in-the-parent-cont/64118136#64118136)

[When to use Xamarin bindings as opposed to passing objects to page constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990624/when-to-use-xamarin-bindings-as-opposed-to-passing-objects-to-page-constructors/63992061#63992061)

Comment: ok makes sense. almost like as if you had a bindingcontext and a private and public property